# Are there any preset pose mode

Tags: mesh, add-on

I want to know is there any addon with ready made pose mode. In human made addon there are few pose mode similar to that is there any addon or website where can i download different type of pose mode.

Comment: Poses are particular to the armature. So it's techically impossible to have a set of premade poses, since every armature is different. And that's why there is no such addon. At least not that i know of. That said, you could use bvh files with the animations that you need.

Comment: @Tiles in the human made addon there are few preset pose mode

Comment: @Tiles a video also i have seen https://vimeo.com/137046614

Comment: The Video is a proof of concept, not an addon. And it also just works with one rig.

Comment: @Tiles have you tried make human addon in that you can see ready presets for poses

Comment: Ah, i have misunderstood you. So you talk about this specific addon. But also here, i don't know of any further poses, sorry. You could contact the author of the addon if he wants to include more poses.